# Is there something with with the string?

Tags: c#, string

So i'm trying to get the username from a notepad, then trying to login into the lib. but it comes up error sayign it doesnt exist... {sorry for english}

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Skype4Sharp;
using Skype4Sharp.Events;
using Skype4Sharp.Auth;
using Skype4Sharp.Helpers;
using Skype4Sharp.Enums;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Contactbombtest {
  class Program {
    static Skype4Sharp.Skype4Sharp mainSkype;
    static SkypeCredentials authCreds;
    private SkypeCredentials skypeCredentials;

    public Program(SkypeCredentials skypeCredentials) {
      this.skypeCredentials = skypeCredentials;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("Please provide the username.");
      string username = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Sending contacts to " + username);
      foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Mikael2\Desktop\skypebomb\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8)) {

        string[] text2 = line.Split(':');
        string getusername = text2[0];
        string getpassword = text2[1];
        Console.WriteLine("[LOG]: Sending request from account:  {0}:{1}", getusername, string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("*", getpassword.Length)));
        mainSkype.Login();
      }
      new Program(new SkypeCredentials(getusername, getpassword));
      while (true) {}
    }

  }
}
```

I always get this error, but i've been trying and trying..
could you please help me?

error message:
Error   CS0103  The name 'getpassword' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0103  The name 'getusername' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Include the code in the question, not a link.

Comment: "skypebomb", what a nice way to learn programming....

Comment: okay sorry it wouldnt let me so i posted a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're declaring your variables inside the for each loop. This means that when the loop is complete the variables are no longer in scope. So when you try and new your Program, they don't exist.

try moving the string declarations outside of the foreach loop.

```
string getpassword = string.Empty;
string getusername = string.Empty;
string[] text2;

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Mikael2\Desktop\skypebomb\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    text2 = line.Split(':');
    getusername = text2[0];
    getpassword = text2[1];
    Console.WriteLine("[LOG]: Sending request from account:  {0}:{1}", getusername, string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("*", getpassword.Length)));
    mainSkype.Login();
}
new Program(new SkypeCredentials(getusername, getpassword));
```

Comment: Now i got a error saying
Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'getusername'

Comment: That's because in my example we weren't assigning a value to the strings when we initialised them. I've updated the example.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for explaining :) it's working now